# Load header in new window, using Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a modal window that opens when clicking on an anchor inside my CodeIgniter application, I want to change it to rather open in a new window rather than in the current modal window. So what I did was just remove the class on the anchor which tells the application to know it's a modal window and then added a target="_blank" to that same anchor, it works as it opens the contents in a new window/tab.

Now for the problem:
There are no stylesheets present in the new window, eventhough at the first line of the "was modal now it's own window" it has the following code:

```
<?php $this->load->view('manager/theheader'); ?>
```

It looks like there's something missing, perhaps something that tells it what $this is? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are missing the instance to CI you can get it using

```
 $ci =& get_instance();
 $ci->load->view('manager/thehearder');
```